# How to call secret manager from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, secret-manager

I am new to AWS. I am trying to establish my lambda function to the AWS Redshift so that I can query the database. I have stored the credentials in the secret key manager.

I understand that the secret key manager has provided a sample code to retrieve the sercet in the application. However, I have no idea how to get going after copying the code in my lambda function.

handler.py

```
# Use this code snippet in your app.
# If you need more information about configurations or implementing the sample code, visit the AWS docs:   
# https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/

import boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def get_secret():

    secret_name = "mykeyname"
    region_name = "myregionname"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
            
    # Your code goes here.
```

How do I check if the connection is established and how do i query from the redshift?

And I understand that we need to have lambda_handler(event,context) in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to run queries in Amazon Redshift.

#### SQL Client

Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL. Therefore, you can use any **SQL Client** that knows how to talk to PostgreSQL.

For Python, a popular choice is to use [Psycopg – PostgreSQL database adapter for Python](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/).

To connect, you would supply an endpoint, username and password. Make sure the Security Group on the Redshift database permits access from the security group associated with the AWS Lambda function.

#### Redshift Data API

A newer way to connect to Redshift is via the **Data API**, which avoids the need for an SQL client.

It uses IAM credentials, so you don't actually need that password stored in Secrets Manager. Also, it does *not* need to be connected to the same VPC as the Redshift database.

Frankly, this sounds like a better way to connect. (I haven't tried it myself yet.)

See: [Announcing Data API for Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/announcing-data-api-for-amazon-redshift/)

Comment: So u are saying that I do not have to establish any connection if it they are the same VPC? Does it mean that I can query it straight away?

Comment: If you use the Data API, you do not need to connect the Lambda function to the VPC. It connects to an endpoint on the Internet. Your Lambda function will require an IAM Role that has permission to access the Redshift cluster (eg `AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess` policy). See: [Using the Amazon Redshift Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html).